# How do I turn my java program into a command line utility on linux?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea

I've written a small command line app in java on ubuntu using intellij idea. I'm compiling my project to a jar file which I can then execute using

```
java -jar myapp.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 etc
```

I would however like to run my app like this:

```
myapp arg1 arg2 arg3
```

How can I achieve this? And how can I do it so that others to whom I send my app can use it the same way?

Comment: If you just want to do this on you own computer, you can use an alias or write a wrapper script. If you want to share your application I would create a deb package. There is a ant/maven plugin called jdeb (https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb) which is pretty handy and easy to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define an alias like (if you want it to be permanent for bash then define it in .bash_aliases in your home directory):

```
alias myapp="java -jar myapp.jar"
```

And then run your command like:

```
myapp arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answers states, you can create alias or make your jar executable, but there's the other option, which makes this solution portable to the other computers even without Java.

You can use `javafxpackager` (`javapackager` since JDK 8u20) tool, the most basic usage of which is following:

```
$ javafxpackager -deploy -native -outdir outdir -outfile outfile -name AppName -appclass package.ClassName -srcdir compiled
```

You can read more documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafxpackager001.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Get to your JAR file and change it to executable

Run your jar file like it was any other binary executable or shell script

```
./myjar.jar
```